# Android app crashes when retrieving Last Known Location with Location Manager for GPS

Tags: android

To be clear: This is an activity in my Android application that is meant to pull the coordinates for the users location using the GPS_PROVIDER. The Activity contains a button which, when pressed, should initiate a method that obtains the coordinate data. The problem is that the application crashes when there is no previously known location information (ie if the phone was recently reset). If I open up the Maps application (for example) and pinpoint my location, then re-open my own application and run this method, it works as intended. My question is why is this crashing and/or how can I prevent this crash from occurring? Help is appreciated, thanks.

This method is run when the button is pressed - and an intent response is generated back to the calling activity when the coordinates are properly found:

```
protected void getCurrentLocation() {
    Location location = null;
    try {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) { }

    if (location != null) {
        longV = location.getLongitude();
        latV  = location.getLatitude();
        response(longV, latV);
    } else {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting in your `logcat`?

Comment: If location is null, you will have an infinite recursion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are receiving a StackOverflowException, because if `location` is `null` you call the exact same function creating an indefinite loop...

If there is no last know location, you need to request a new location. (`getLastKnownLocation()` will not change on its own no matter how many times you call it.)

Comment: You are correct in that I am receiving a StackOverflowException, and logically this makes perfect sense to me as to why - My next question would be, what method(s) should I look into to tell it to continue to try and retrieve my current location for my "else" clause? I have this up in the main scope of the class, is there anything else I am missing/should try? locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                locationListener
        );

Comment: That looks great, when the next location arrives you receive it in `LocationListener#onLocationChanged()`. If you only want one update look for `LocationManager#requestSingleUpdate()` (API 9+).

Comment: Thank you for you rapid responses, I appreciate the help.